# Can cache.addAll accept wildcard matches?

Tags: javascript, html, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

Is there a way to match wildcard URLs on a `serviceWorker`'s `install` event?

I'd like to be able to match something like `*.bundle.js`.

```
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(latest.cache).then(cache => {
      return cache.addAll([
        '/',
        '*.bundle.js'
      ])
    })
  )
})
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think that's possible since you're not caching strings or urls, but requests.

There is a thing from Google that might be of use, [the sw-precache module](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache). This can generate a service worker through Gulp or the commandline. It works alongside the [service worker toolbox](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-toolbox).

Comment: FYI: The successor of these is called Workbox https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/